# geneticLHS function in lhs package

Tags: r

I want to ask your help for a problem that I encountered while using "lhs" package of R program. I want to produce samples for my parameters with "geneticlhs" and "optimumlhs".. I write a code like this ,

```
install.packages("lhs") 
library(lhs)
set.seed(1234)
g=geneticLHS(n=5000, k=5, pop = 100, gen = 4, pMut = 0.1, criterium = "S", verbose = FALSE)
m=196*g[,1]+4
ro=g[,2]
s_plus=g[,3]
s_minus=ro*g[,4]
b=98*g[,5]+2
results=cbind(m,ro,s_plus,s_minus,b)
print(results)
write.csv(results, file="geneticLHS.csv")^
```

But it doesnt give response for sample size 5000..when I write 100 or 500 it can produce samples but for 5000 it seem that it will run forever..

What can I do for this? Taking the default values of  "pop, gen, pMut" parameters is wrong?

Thanks for your help from now...